# What is this sequence?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers, stirling-numbers

This is again a question that I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260509/what-is-this-sequence) at Stack Exchange, but got no answer so far, so I am trying here.
Let:

$$ a_n=\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1) {n+2\brack k+2}(n+2)^kB_k$$
$B_k$ is the Bernoulli number. ${n\brack {k}}\;$ is the unsigned Stirling number of first kind,  $\left( {0\brack {0}}\;=1 \text{  and  }{{n}\brack {k}}\;=(n-1){{n-1}\brack {k}}\;+{{n-1}\brack {k-1}}\;\right)$.

From $n=0$, the first terms  are:  $ \ \  1\ ,\ 0\ ,\ -5\ ,\ 0\ ,\ 238\ ,\ 0\ ,\ -51508\ ,\ 0\ ,\ 35028576\ , ..$

The $a_n$ are all integers, and the odd-indexed $a_{2n+1}$ vanish.

A generating function should be even, but I could not find it.

Also, any possible combinatorial interpretation (when removing the sign)?

I would welcome any help or indication on this. Thank you in advance.

EDIT(01/09/18): Actually, this is a particular case of: 
$$ a_{n,h}=\sum_{k\ge0}{k+h-1\choose k} {n\brack h+k}n^k B_k$$
Here is a table for $a_{n,h}$, for $1\le n,h \le 9$.

\begin{matrix}
n&|&a_{n,1}&a_{n,2}&a_{n,3}&a_{n,4}&a_{n,5}&a_{n,6}&a_{n,7}&a_{n,8}&a_{n,9}\\
-&&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
1&|&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
2&|&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
3&|&-1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
4&|&0&-5&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
5&|&24&0&-15&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
6&|&0&238&0&-35&0&1&0&0&0\\
7&|&-3396&0&1281&0&-70&0&1&0&0\\
8&|&0&-51508&0&4977&0&-126&0&1&0\\
9&|&1706112&0&-408700&0&15645&0&-210&0&1\\
\end{matrix}

I know now how to show that $a_{n,h}$ is integer, and that it is zero when $n-h$ is odd. But the proofs that I have found are quite lengthy, technical, and not really enlightening about the mathematical signification of these numbers.

Any idea?

Comment: I note that OP has put this sequence up on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, http://oeis.org/A286483

Comment: @Gerry, I did add it on the OEIS, because I was told it was not there, and I was hoping to advertise about it.

Comment: Might have been a good idea to mention that, so as to prevent people from wasting their time looking it up.

Comment: They seem to have alternating signs.

Comment: One can check that $a_n \mod {n+1}$ is either $0$ or $n-1$ for all $n\leq 100$.

Comment: It seems that $a_{p-1} = p-2 (mod p)$ if $p$ is prime and $a_{n} = 0 (mod n+1)$ if $n+1$ is not prime.

Comment: Seemingly one actually also gets integers with *signed* Stirling numbers, with alternating signs (but no zeroes)

Comment: The diagonals $a_{n+k,n}$ for fixed even $k$ seem to be polynomials in $n$ of the form $p_k(n)(n+k+1)\cdots (n+1)n$ where $p_k(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k-2$.

Comment: @Martin Rubey.   yes: it can be shown that $a_{n,n-k}$ is a polynomial of degree $2k$. And indeed $n=-1,0,1,\cdot \cdot \cdot, k$ seem to be roots, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Two other things that can be shown: (i) $a_{n,k} \equiv \frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}}{2}{n \brack k} \bmod n$  and (ii) $a_{n,1} \equiv -1 \bmod n$ iff $n$ is odd prime   ($ \equiv 0$ otherwise).

Answer (score 5):

I've got that $a_{n,h}$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in
\begin{split}
&(-1)^{n+h+1} \frac{n!}{2\cdot (h-1)!}\frac{\log(1+x)^{h}\left(\coth(-\frac{n}2\log(1+x))-1\right)}{1+x} \\
=\ &(-1)^{n+h} \frac{n!}{(h-1)!}\frac{\log(1+x)^{h}}{(1-(1+x)^{-n})(1+x)}.
\end{split}
It's yet unclear if the dependency on $n$ can be eliminated to turn this expression into a generating function.

Comment: That is some progress.  Can this expression be used to show that $a_{n,h}$ is zero when $n-h$ is odd?